# 'download pre-built shared index' in PyCharm. What does this mean?

Tags: pycharm

when I start up my PyCharm IDE it asks me whether I want to 'download pre-built shared index'. What does this mean? And should I select 'Always Download'?

I have previously selected options but I cannot discern what effect it is having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing in PyCharm is helping out IDE for: code completion, inspections, finding usages, navigation, syntax highlighting, and refactorings.

So in-short it is trying to index (keep) all the shared libraries, packages and files that is related to your current project or present as a global package to help you out with code suggessions.

This is not only true for PyCharm but all Jetbrains products give this feature. For example if I am using Intellij Idea and having some external JARs' (packages) in my project. So if I allowed IntelliJ Idea to index the files it will check and help me out for code completion and more suggestions on the fly.

Read more about it [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/indexing.html)

I also select **Always Download** option.

Comment: hey nice one @Piyush Pranjal ! Thank you for your explanation and link.

Comment: I also found this link useful in the end too... https://coder.com/blog/faster-jetbrains-ides-with-shared-indexes